# Spring Data mongoTemplate.save() behaviour

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When you persisting a document using mongoTemplate.save() it destroys all unmapped fields in the database document.

For example, you have a collection "myDocument" with the document in the mongodb:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("552402c3186eb112488b45ea"),
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2"
}
```

and your domain object looks like:

```
public class MyDocument {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String field1;

  // getter and setter
}
```

after **updating** your document:

```
MyDocument doc = myDocumentRepository.getById(<some_id>);
doc.setField1("value3");
mongoTemplate.save(doc);
```

you will get the document in the collection without "field2":

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("552402c3186eb112488b45ea"),
  "field1": "value3"
}
```

It looks like unexpected behaviour and may be a real stopper when few different applications are using the same database.

Is overriding of MongoTemplate method is acceptable workaround? 
Any other ideas will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

**update**

As noted by @helmy this is how mongoTemplate.save() works and usage of update methods is preferred. But in this case I'm loosing lifecycle events that built into mongodb mapping framework. For example, validation will not works on update as it triggered by listener in onBeforeSave event...

Comment: "…when few different applications are using the same database." — I'd argue that's a fundamental architectural problem.

Comment: @OliverGierke Yes, but it is common situation. Sadly, it's not a perfect world :)

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm the architectural problems are inherent in having a common data store, whether you expose the raw DB or some API server. The relevant difference is that the DB is more powerful, which can be a bonus or a problem depending on what kinds of data-accessing clients you have. From that perspective, an application server accessing MongoDB needs to have a choice whether it takes full control of the schema (drop all unknown fields) or not (retain them).

Answer (score 6):

That's not unexpected or surprising at all, that's how [save()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) works -- it overwrites the **entire** document.

I'd suggest that you take a look at the Spring [Update](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e1751) class to perform your updates.

Comment: It is unexpected at least for me, as other frameworks have not such behaviour. For example Doctrine will not override unmapped fields and it looks sensible for me because if the field is not mapped it gives a clue that I don't want to manage it.   

Any way, update of the document is not included by Spring developers in the document lifecycle and thus does not emits lifecycle events. It brings a lot of inconvenience. Can you suggest something?...

Comment: It's very unexpected for me, too. I'm coming from Ruby and MongoID under Ruby does NOT erase unmapped fields. I mean common on! Seriously? That's a totally bullshit behaviour! And what is this MongoTemplate? Why I need it? In Ruby life is much easier, but now I have to deal with this bullshit :-( I appreciate any help.